# How to convert Array<MutableSet<String>?> to IntArray

Tags: android, kotlin

Error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<MutableSet<String>?> but IntArray was expected
```

Code:

```
  fun tab10(): IntArray {
        var Arr1 = arrayOf(player.chart_keys)
        return Arr1
  }
```

chart_keys is in a different class Player

```
var chart_keys: MutableSet<String>? = mutableSetOf(),
```

Is it possible?

Comment: what is `IntArray` Show which code produces this error

Comment: @johnrao07 what is `player.chart_keys`

Comment: `arrayOf` will create an array of whatever you pass into it. Therefore, passing a `MutableSet<String>`into it will create array of `MutableSet<String>`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Is there a way to change it to IntArray

The data returned is a simple comma-separated Array

Comment: kotlin can't predict how exactly you want to convert set of Strings to array of Integers.Therefore you have to tell it explicitly (by implementing manually)

Comment: What is `chart_keys`? Why does it have a `_` instead of `K`? Why is the set mutable? Can it be immutable?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - and nullable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map Strings to Ints and then convert the Set to an IntArray. This might work:

```
player.chart_keys?.map { it.toInt() }?.toIntArray()
   ?: intArrayOf()
```

Comment: I think it would be `player.chart_keys?.map { it.toInt() }.toIntArray()`, and I'm not sure if ones better than the other but instead of `intArrayOf()` I would use `emptyArray()`

Comment: Good catch! You'll notice in my edit that I only spotted it was nullable after writing that line! Fixing now :) Are sure emptyArray() can create an IntArray?

Comment: ah, you're right - `emptyArray()` makes a `Array<Int>` - just ignore the second half of my comment